# angularjs error on iPad(first generation)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ipad

I'm getting this error on an iPad (first generation, the only iPad I have) while trying to use a very basic use of `ngRoute` and `ngAnimate`. It works on desktops and on iPhone(6), but not the iPad. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error[$injector:modulerr]http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=ng&p1='undefined%20is%20not%20an%20object
```

This is the simple app I'm using:

```
var app = angular.module('openRoute', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

.when('/news', {
templateUrl : 'news.html'
})

.when('/info', {
    templateUrl: 'info.html'
})


});
```

And this is the HTML with all the links necessary:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2/style.css" />
    <script src="style2/prefixfree.min.js"></script>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
         <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
         <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    </head>
    <body ng-app="openRoute">
```

Anyone makes sense out of this?

Comment: Sounds like a browser support problem. Try not using an extremely outdated version of the iPad and it should work.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed it could be as simple as a browser support problem cause of the outdated ipad. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have an dependency injection mechanism that i don't see.

You need to give the key to the dependency then the actual setting of the value, see the example below

```
angular
    .module('ModuleName')
    .config(['$httpProvider', '$compileProvider', '$resourceProvider',
        function($httpProvider, $compileProvider, $resourceProvider) {
            // do stuff
        }]);
```